# Solr: Default search on dynamic fields

Tags: java, solr

Is it possible to configure dynamic fields as default search fields? More specifically in`SearchHandler`'s `df` or `edismax`'s `qf` field listings?

I've been searching on this but could find a solution. I understand that `copyField` can be used for my requirement, but wanted to know if there are other alternatives.